# Endpoint check for correctness

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I have been searching the internet and have not been able to find a solution to my problem.

I want to be able to check the correctness and availability of a WCF service through a passed in endpoint. So the user inputs an endpoint (it changes a lot) and I want to be able to make sure it is valid by some form of ping or check.

I have been looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.discoveryservice.aspx) but it does not seem to do what I am looking for.

Comment: Can you not just send a test message with no content?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `OpenTimeout` of your clients binding to a reasonable short time and call your clients `Open()` method.

If the service is not there/answering, you will get a *System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException*.  Or your service could implement a `"Ping()"` method, that gives you a sensible result you can check, and call this "Ping()" without calling `Open()` first. So you can check availability and correctness with one call.

Answer (score 0):

You could download excellent example from IDesign site (the writer of 'Programming WCF Services')

Here is the link: [iDesign](http://www.idesign.net/Downloads)

Take a look on 'Ad-hoc Discovery' and 'Metadata Explorer'